# How to keep labels at multiples of e.g. 5 for a scrolling chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, axis-labels

I have a winforms chart which is bound to a List. Every two seconds a new measurement is added to the list. My program is zooming to a 25 second interval and then scrolling to the end of the chart. I would like the x-axis to show multiples of 5 (5, 10, 15, 20...).

[image: chart with rounded labels]

In the beginning it works fine, but then when the chart grows bigger and scrolling begins the labels, ticks and gridlines shift (e.g. 23, 28, 33, 38...).

[image]

How do I change this so it shows 25, 30, 35, 40... instead?

Here is my code for the chart:

```
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 5D;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 5D;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 5D;
chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = 0D;
chartArea1.AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 5D;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.Position = 0D;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 25D;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = false;
chartArea1.AxisX.Title = "Time [s]";
chartArea1.AxisY.Interval = 20D;
chartArea1.AxisY.Title = "Cold pump\\nVol. [ml]";
chartArea1.Name = "ChartColdPump";
chartArea1.Position.Auto = false;
chartArea1.Position.Height = 25F;
chartArea1.Position.Width = 99F;
```

And the code for the scrolling, called each time a new measurement is added to the list:

```
componentsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(ScrollType.Last);
```

Comment: You probably should change the scolling code in a way that keeps your starting/minimum value at a multiple of 5.. (Btw: The question title is totally misleading! A rounded label is not even a similar thing as an odd number let alone a multiple of 5)

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. (Sorry, I did my best to describe my problem, but was struggling since English is not my first language. How would you describe "nice looking numbers" then?)

Comment: Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder. I'll try to help ;-)

Comment: See the updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt the various interval offsets to keep the labels at multiples of `5` or any other `Interval` you want.

Here is an example:

```
Axis ax = componentsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX; ;

ax.ScaleView.Scroll(ScrollType.Last);

int i1     = (int)ax.ScaleView.Position - 1;  // by default labels start at 1
int mult   = (int)ax.LabelStyle.Interval;
int offset = i1 % mult  == 0 ? 0 : mult  - (i1 % mult );

ax.IntervalOffset = offset;
ax.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = offset;
```

Note that the default label start is at `1`; you override it by setting a `Minimum` but after scrolling this no longer holds. So we need an offset to shift the intervals by the right amount..

[image]

Comment: It works... sometimes. Here some debugging info:
`sec = 0, i1 = -1, offset = 26/
sec = 9, i1 = 2147483647, offset = 3/
sec = 11, i1 = 2147483647, offset = 3/
sec = 14, i1 = -1, offset = 26/
sec = 16, i1 = 1, offset = 24/
sec = 18, i1 = 1, offset = 24`

Where sec is the XAxis value of the last added data to the chart.

I do not understand what `ScaleView.Position` does. The docs aren't really helpful. Is it the XAxis value of the left most visible point of the chart?

Comment: Forgot to mention: the interval used here is 25, not 5.

Comment: _I do not understand what ScaleView.Position does. The docs aren't really helpful. Is it the XAxis value of the left most visible point of the chart?_ Yes, that's what it is. What happens when it doesn't work? Offset should always stay between 0 and 24 in your cases then..

Comment: When the chart starts drawing and scrolling is not necessary yet, sometimes `i1==0` and sometime `i1==1`. For `i1==0` everything works fine. For `i1==1` the grid draws at 24, 49, 74, etc. I cannot figure out why `i1` has different values for different runs of the application.

Comment: BTW: Shouldn't the scrolling be done before the offset calculation. Scrolling alters the `ScaleView.Position`, right?

Comment: Yes, first scroll then adapt the offset. (sorry a  copy and past error of mine! corrected..) Some of those values `i1 = 2147483647` hit the size limit for ints. Is that on purpose? could it be that they roll over?

Comment: No, it is because on startup the chart is not visible and `ScaleView.Position == Double.NaN`. As soon as the chart becomes visible they are assigned normal values.